# Updated for ios7 in monodevelop but it is giving error

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Now,I have updated my `Xamarin.ios` to `7.0.x` It is giving error that, I am already having `xcode 5`

```
Error: A valid Xcode installation could not be found. If your copy of Xcode is 
installed to a non-standard prefix, please specify the location in MonoDevelop's
Preferences under 'SDK Locations'. (Scrapboom.iPhone)
```

I have updated Xcode to 5.0 for ios7 and running application in monodevelop but application is not running it is giving,

**warning on simulator**:

```
warning MT1201: Could not load the simulator: dlopen(Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient, 1): image not found
```

**warning on device:**

```
warning MT1003: Could not kill the application 'com.scrapboom.iphone'. You may have to kill the application manually.
error MT0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory 'Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport' not found.
  at System.IO.Directory.ValidateDirectoryListing (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean& stop) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Installation.Device.get_DeveloperImagePath () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Installation.Device.MountDeveloperImage () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Installation.Installer.FindApplication (MonoTouch.Installation.Device d, System.String appId) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Installation.Installer+<LaunchApplication>c__AnonStorey1A.<>m__22 (MonoTouch.Installation.Device d) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Have you modified the SDK location in Xamarin Studio? And where did you install Xcode 5?

Comment: I have installed Xcode in Applications folder.Application is running in xamarin studio but it is giving error in monodevelop.I dont know how to set the location of SDK.               Error: A valid Xcode installation could not be found. If your copy of Xcode is installed to a non-standard prefix, please specify the location in MonoDevelop's Preferences under 'SDK Locations'. (Scrapboom.iPhone)

Comment: Open Xamarin Studio's Preferences, go to Projects/SDK Locations/Apple and see if anything is non-default there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the new `XCode` location in `Xamarin.Studio` in the Preferences:

```
Xamarin Studio > Preferences... > Projects > SDK Locations > Apple
```

[image: Xamarin studio preferences]

If you don't have the green check marks, set the location targetting your new `XCode 5` installation (usually `/Applications/XCode.App`)

Comment: Application is working fine in Xamarin studio but it is not working Monodevelop.I already have green checks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after updating to Xcode6. What helped me was installing all updates for Xamarin Studio over the beta channel. Go to Xamarin Studio > Check for Updates ... an then choose **beta** instead of **stable**